# TableView y setOnCloseListener JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

mi problema es que cuando cargo el .txt en el tableview lo carga pero no sale el texto en las columnas, sale vació pero cuando selecciono la fila si que recoge los datos que pertenecen a cada columna pero en la tabla no salen y por mas que miro en internet esta bien escrito el codigo...

Y segun he visto por internet existe el setOnCloseListener() que detecta cuando se cierra o se va a cerrar y poder hacer algo al respecto y tanpoco me funciona. La idea es añadir y eliminar objetos a la tabla.

[image: El error del que hablo]

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Controller

```
package flightfx;

import flightfx.model.Flight;
import flightfx.utils.FileUtils;
import flightfx.utils.MessageUtils;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.OptionalDouble;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class FXMLMainViewController implements Initializable {

    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Flight> TV;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Flight, String> TVFlightNumber;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Flight, String> TVDestination;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Flight, LocalDateTime> TVDeparture;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Flight, LocalTime> TVDuration;
    @FXML
    private TextField TextFlightNumber;
    @FXML
    private TextField TextDestination;
    @FXML
    private TextField TextDeparture;
    @FXML
    private TextField TextDuration;
    @FXML
    private Button ButtonAdd;
    @FXML
    private Button ButtonDelete;
    @FXML
    private Button ButtonFilter;
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> TextChoiseBox;

    private List<Flight> flights;
    private ObservableList<Flight> currentFlight;   



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        //Creo el contenido del ChoiceBox para hacer el filtro
        TextChoiseBox.setItems(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList("Show all flights", 
                        "Show flights to currently selected city","Show long flights", 
                        "Show next 5 flights" ,"Show flight duration average")); 
        //Selecciono el primero 
        TextChoiseBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

        try {
            //Cargo en el List los vuelos del fichero txt
            flights = FileUtils.loadFlights();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLMainViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
            //Llamo a la funcion donde carga la tabla segun el filtro escogido
            loadTable();

        if(TV.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null){ 
            //Si no hay nada seleccionado de la tabla el boton pasa a ser desactivado
            ButtonDelete.setDisable(true);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Vacio los cambios despues de insertar
     */
    private void clearTextFields(){
        TextFlightNumber.setText("");
        TextDestination.setText("");
        TextDeparture.setText("");
        TextDuration.setText("");        
    }
    /**
     * Haciendo click al boton añado el vuelo a la lista y saldra en la tabla
     * @param event 
     */
    @FXML
    private void ButtonAddAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException 
    {
        Flight flight = null;
        DateTimeFormatter dtfDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        DateTimeFormatter dtfHour = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm");
        //Compruebo que no esten vacios
        if (TextFlightNumber.getText().equals("") || TextDestination.getText().equals("")|| TextDeparture.getText().equals("")|| TextDuration.getText().equals("")){
            MessageUtils.showMessage(" the Flight number, Destination, Date and Duration can't be empty");
        }
        else
        {
            //Añado el vuelo y le doy el formato a los LocalDateTime y LocalTime
            flight = new Flight(TextFlightNumber.getText(),TextDestination.getText(), LocalDateTime.parse(TextDeparture.getText(),dtfDate),LocalTime.parse(TextDuration.getText(),dtfHour)); 
        }
        if (flight != null){
            //Añado el vuelo a la Lista
            flights.add(flight);
            currentFlight.add(flight);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Haciendo click al boton eliminar recogo el vuelo seleccionado y lo elimino
     * @param event 
     */
    @FXML
    private void ButtonDeleteAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Flight flight = TV.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        //Saco una ventana de confirmacion en caso de querer eliminarlo
        if (MessageUtils.confirmationMessage()){
            flights.remove(flight);            
            currentFlight.remove(flight);
            TV.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            clearTextFields(); 
            FileUtils.saveFlights(flights);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Inicio la tabla con sus columnas y añado los vuelos
     */
    private void initializeFlightsTable() { 
        //Si la tabla no tiene nada sacar el mensaje
        TV.setPlaceholder(new Label("No Flights to show"));
        //Unir el id del formulario de las columnas con los atributos de la clase Flight
        TVFlightNumber.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Flight,String>("flightNumber"));
        TVDestination.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Flight,String>("destination"));
        TVDeparture.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Flight,LocalDateTime>("time"));
        TVDuration.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Flight,LocalTime>("duration"));
        //Añadir los vuelos
        TV.setItems(currentFlight);
        //Obtengo los valores del vuelo seleccionado para habilitar o no el boton de eliminar
        TV.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
            if (newSelection != null) {
                TextFlightNumber.setText(newSelection.GetFlightNumber());
                TextDestination.setText(newSelection.GetDestination());
                TextDeparture.setText(newSelection.GetTime().toString());
                TextDuration.setText(newSelection.GetDuration().toString());               
                ButtonDelete.setDisable(false);
            } else {
                ButtonDelete.setDisable(true);
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Cargo la tabla respecto al filtro escogido
     */
    private void loadTable() {
        switch(TextChoiseBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()) {
            case 0:
                filterAllFlight();
                break;
            case 1:
                filterSelectedDestination();
                break;
            case 2:
                filterFlightAverage();
                break;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Al pinchar en el boton del filtro carga la tabla
     * @param event 
     */
    @FXML
    private void ButtonFilterAction(ActionEvent event) {
        loadTable();
    }
    /**
     * Se filtra todos los vuelos (por defecto siempre sera este ya que muestra todos los vuelos)
     */
    private void filterAllFlight() {
        currentFlight = FXCollections.observableArrayList(flights);
        initializeFlightsTable();
    }
    /**
     * Se filtra el promedio de minutos de los vuelos
     */
    private void filterFlightAverage() {
        //Creo una expresion lambda que dara un formato double para el promedio de minutos
        //Filtro las duraciones que no sean nulas, paso a double, la duracion de horas las multiplico por 60 para pasarlas
        //a minutos y las sumo con los minutos haciendo un promedio con el resultado
        OptionalDouble avgDuration = flights.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.GetDuration() != null)
                .mapToDouble(e -> ((e.GetDuration().getHour()*60) + e.GetDuration().getMinute())).average();
        Double n = avgDuration.orElse(0);
        //Luego divido entre 60 para sacar las horas
        n = n/60;
        MessageUtils.showMessage(String.format("The average of the selected flights is %.2f", n));

    }
    /**
     * Se filtra por el destino seleccionado
     */
    private void filterSelectedDestination() {
        //recogo el destino seleccionado
        Flight flight = TV.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        //guardo solo el nombre del destino
        String destination = flight.GetDestination();
        //limpio la tabla
        currentFlight.clear();
        //recorro los vuelos y comparo los destinos para despues agregar los que son iguales
        for (Flight e : flights) {
            if (e.GetDestination().equals(destination))
                currentFlight.add(e);
        }        
        //inicio la tabla
        initializeFlightsTable();
    } 
    //Cuando cierro el Listener (escucha) guardo los vuelos en el txt
    public void setOnCloseListener(Stage stage) {
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            if (!MessageUtils.confirmationMessage())
                e.consume();
            else{
                try {                
                    FileUtils.saveFlights(flights);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FXMLMainViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

La clase Flight

```
package flightfx.model;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

/**
 *
 * @author killtrols
 */
public class Flight {
    private  String flightNumber;
    private  String destination;
    private  LocalDateTime time;
    private  LocalTime duration;

    public Flight(String newFlightNumber)
    {
        flightNumber = newFlightNumber;
    }
    public Flight(String newFlightNumber,String newDestination,LocalDateTime newTime,LocalTime newDuration)
    {       
        flightNumber = newFlightNumber;
        destination = newDestination;
        time = newTime;
        duration = newDuration;
    }
    public void SetFlightNumber(String newFlightNumber)
    {
        flightNumber = newFlightNumber;
    }
    public String GetFlightNumber()
    {
        return flightNumber;
    }
    public void SetDestination(String newDestination)
    {
        destination = newDestination;
    }
    public String GetDestination()
    {
        return destination;
    }
    public void SetTime(LocalDateTime newTime)
    {        
        time = newTime;
    }
    public LocalDateTime GetTime()
    {
        return time;
    }
    public void SetDuration(LocalTime newDuration)
    {
        duration = newDuration;
    }
    public LocalTime GetDuration()
    {
        return duration;
    }
    public String getData() {
        String data;
        if (destination == null && time == null && duration == null)
            data = flightNumber;
        else
            data = flightNumber + ";" + destination + ";" + time + ";" + duration;
        return data;
    }
}
```

La clase donde se guarda y carga el txt

```
package flightfx.utils;

import flightfx.model.Flight;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 *
 * @author killtrols
 */
public class FileUtils {


    private static final String EXAMS_LIST_FILE = "flights.txt";

    public static List<Flight> loadFlights() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        List<Flight> listFlight = new ArrayList<Flight>();
        DateTimeFormatter dtfDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        DateTimeFormatter dtfHour = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm");


        FileReader file = new FileReader(EXAMS_LIST_FILE);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(file);
        String read;
        while((read = in.readLine()) != null)
        {           
            String[] split = read.split(";");  

            listFlight.add(new Flight(split[0],split[1],LocalDateTime.parse(split[2],dtfDate),LocalTime.parse(split[3],dtfHour)));            
        }
        return listFlight;        
    }
    public static void saveFlights(List<Flight> saveFlight) throws IOException
    {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        DateTimeFormatter dtfHour = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm");
        BufferedWriter writer;
        String line;
        File file = new File("flights.txt");
        if(file.exists())
        {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
            line = saveFlight.get(0).GetFlightNumber() + ";" + saveFlight.get(0).GetDestination() + ";" + saveFlight.get(0).GetTime().format(dtfDate) + ";" + saveFlight.get(0).GetDuration().format(dtfHour);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write(line);
            writer.close();
        }
        else if(!file.exists())
        {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,false));
            line = saveFlight.get(0).GetFlightNumber() + ";" + saveFlight.get(0).GetDestination() + ";" + saveFlight.get(0).GetTime().format(dtfDate) + ";" + saveFlight.get(0).GetDuration().format(dtfHour);
            writer.write(line);
            writer.close();
        }

    }  
    /*public static List<Flight> loadFlights(){

        DateTimeFormatter dtfDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        DateTimeFormatter dtfHour = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm");
        List<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(
            Paths.get("", EXAMS_LIST_FILE))) {

            flights = stream.map(line -> {
                        String[] data = line.split(";");

                        if (data.length == 1)
                            return new Flight(data[0]);
                        else
                            return new Flight(data[0],data[1],LocalDateTime.parse(data[2],dtfDate),LocalTime.parse(data[3],dtfHour));
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File " + EXAMS_LIST_FILE + " doesn't exist!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error reading exams in file " + EXAMS_LIST_FILE);
            flights = new ArrayList<>(); // Empty list if it fails to read file
        }

        return flights;
    }

    public static void saveFlights(List<Flight> exams) {
        try (PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(
                Paths.get("", EXAMS_LIST_FILE).toFile())) {

            for (Flight e : exams) {
                print.println(e.getData());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error writing: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Parece que el `loadTable` que tienes en el `initialize` no se está llamando. De todos modos todo este bloque de código debería ir dentro del boloque `try`, pásalo dentro y prueba: `loadTable();

        if(TV.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null){ 
            //Si no hay nada seleccionado de la tabla el boton pasa a ser desactivado
            ButtonDelete.setDisable(true);
        }` Otra posible causa es que al inciar, no se cumpla ninguna de las condiciones que evalúas en el `switch`: `TextChoiseBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()`

Comment: Hola buenas, lo he pasado todo dentro del Try y sigue igual, sobre lo del switch, el TextChoiseBox ya tiene definido 1 valor: `TextChoiseBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Show all flights","Show flights to currently selected city","Show long flights","Show next 5 flights" ,"Show flight duration average"));//Selecciono el primero TextChoiseBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst(); ` entonces cuando va al switch coge el valor 0 pq seria la primera posicion que le pongo y se ejecutaria todo. Eso es lo que he querido programar, ahora bien, no se si esta correcto,hare alguna comprobacion

Comment: He creado otro Controller donde solo ejecuto el loadFlights, creo el FXCollections, las columnas(setCellValueFactory etc) y el setItems y nada, el problema es el mismo

Comment: Lo primero que tienes que hacer es ir depurando tus variables y las llamadas que vas haciendo al método, para verificar que el código está siguiendo esa lógica o no. O sea, en el `initialize` poner un `System.out.println`  de `TextChoiseBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();`, en el `loadTable` lo mismo... y así imprimir cada variable que interviene, puede que alguna condición no es esté cumpliendo o que el código no siga la lógica que crees que sigue.

Comment: Depura también en cada paso el valor de `currentFlight` y revisa si la tabla es correcta en el archivo XML, que tiene más o menos esta estructura: `<TableView fx:id="idDeTabla" layoutX="871.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="589.0" prefWidth="240.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="idColumn" prefWidth="37.0" text="C1" visible="false" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tituloColumn" prefWidth="236.0" text="Título" />
        </columns>
        <items>
       <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
       </FXCollections>
   </items>
      </TableView>`

Comment: Ya lo conseguí, revisando vi que tenia GetNumberFlight y el programa el `TVFlightNumber.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Flight,String>("flightNumber"));` estaba buscando la propiedad getNumberFlight al final era una tonteria muy simple, al venir de C# eso no ocurria.Solucionado esto, viene la otra duda. El setOnCloseListener no me funciona y encontre poco acerca de esto, lo que encontre decia que tenia que declararlo en la clase del main, hacer el evento y acceder a la lista del controller y guardarlo en el txt. Mi duda es que nunca vi este tipo de evento, alguien sabria ayudarme?

Comment: Cual era el error en tu codigo? Es que lo tengo que hacer yo también y no ha manera de que me salga la lista ni nada....

Comment: yo tambien obtengo el mismo error solo que a mi solo me saca los destino y el tiempo, el numero no
y es tambien a la hora de leer fichero y llevarlo a tabla.

Comment: @CarlaLiarte Por favor, no uses las respuestas para poner comentarios. Comprendo que aún no tienes puntos para comentar en todas las publicaciones, pero ese no es el camino a seguir.

Comment: @CarlaLiarte Mi problema venia en la clase Flight que habia declarado GetNumberFlight con la primera en mayuscula y por lo visto Java diferencia eso, no como C# entonces para solucionarlo solo cambie el GetNumberFlight por getNumberFlight

Comment: Esta pregunta está abierta o ya se solucionó?

Answer (score 2):

Esto me paso a mi muchas veces y el detalle es simple. Sobre todo cuando trabajaba con FXML. El asunto lo solvente cuando inicialice la tabla y los datos de la tabla en el controlador del mismo siendo de esta manera.

Variables

```
@FXML
    private ObservableList<Modelo_Inventario> datos = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML 
    private TableColumn<Modelo_Inventario, String> cota;

@FXML 
    private TableView<Modelo_Inventario> inventario;

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    **cota**.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<**Modelo_Inventario**, **String**>("**cota**"));

    **nombreDelObjeto**.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<**clase**, **Tipo de dato**>("**variable de clase**"));

}

public class Modelo_Inventario {

    private String cota;
    private Pane contenedor;
    //Constructor
    //SETTERs y GETTERs

}
```

Si notas el nombreDelObjeto es la variable declarada como `TableColumn`, clase representa la clase que contiene los atributos mapeados por la tabla. El tipo de dato se refiere si es `int`, `string`, etc., y la variable de clase debe ser el nombre del atributo referenciado de la clase que mapea los datos. Así es como se inicializa cada columna de la tabla. Debes hacerlo con todas.