# ¿Cómo añadir datos de un archivo a un cuadro en javafx?

Tags: java

Tengo un archivo, el contenido quiero cargarlo en una lista a traves de un boton "cargar", luego esta lista contiene datos de los cuales debo hacer tres prioridades (tres colas de prioridad) y tres cuadros en java fx, y cargar los datos de cada cola de prioridad en cada cuadro.

Comment: Hola Michelle, has tratado algo de esto que preguntas? podrìas agregar el código y serìa mas fácil ayudarte!:) saludos

Answer (score 0):

Primero seria cargar el archivo en memoria. Aquí te dejo una código:

```
    public List<String> cargarArchivo(String direccion){
       List<String> lineas = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Path ruta = Paths.get(direccion);

        Stream<String> flujoFormateado = Files.lines(ruta, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); // cargando el archivo plano
        flujoFormateado.forEach(lineas::add); // almacenando todos los elementos para su analisis

        System.out.println("lineas guardadas: "+lineas.size());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Archivo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
   return lineas;
}
```

Luego te sugiero ver una respuesta asociada a cargar datos dentro de la tabla aca en el forum.

[JavaFX tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115803/tableview-y-setoncloselistener-javafx?answertab=votes#tab-top)